# Deleting physical file using Android content provider MediaStore.Files.getContentUri(VOLUME_NAME_EXTERNAL)

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

My current Android Application stores pdf files on external storage using

```
 val contentUri = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri(VOLUME_NAME_EXTERNAL)
```

The application creates a sub folder in the standard Documents folder.

My manifest contains

```
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage = true
```

For Android 30 I request the following

```
val intent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION)
                val uri = Uri.fromParts("package", packageName, null)
                intent.data = uri
                startActivity(intent)
```

I have a background worker that attempts to clear all down loaded files, the code I employ is as follows:-

```
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
override suspend fun doActualFlowedWork(): Result {
    if (hasSdkHigherThan(Build.VERSION_CODES.P)) {
        clearDownloadFiles()
    } else {
        clearDownloadLegacyFiles()
    }

    return result ?: Result.success()
}

@Suppress("BlockingMethodInNonBlockingContext")
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
private fun clearDownloadFiles() {
    val resolver = context.contentResolver
    val relativeLocation = "${Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS}${MY_SUB_FOLDER}"

    val contentUri = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri(VOLUME_NAME_EXTERNAL)

    resolver.query(
        contentUri,
        arrayOf(MediaStore.MediaColumns._ID, MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH),
        "${MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH}=?",
        arrayOf(relativeLocation),
        null
    ).use { cursor ->

        cursor?.let {
            while (it.moveToNext()) {

                val idIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns._ID)
                val displayNameIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME)
                val relativePathNameIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH)

                if (cursor.getString(relativePathNameIndex) == relativeLocation) {

                    val fileContentUri = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri(VOLUME_NAME_EXTERNAL, cursor.getLong(idIndex))
                    val count = context.contentResolver.delete(fileContentUri, null, null)
                    if (count == 0) Timber.e("FAILED to clear downloaded file = ${cursor.getString(displayNameIndex)}")
                    else Timber.i("Cleared downloaded file = ${cursor.getString(displayNameIndex)}")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Suppress("DEPRECATION")
private fun clearDownloadLegacyFiles() {
    val documentsFolder = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS)
    if (!documentsFolder.exists()) return

    val mendeleyLiteSubFolder = File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "${Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS}$MY_SUB_FOLDER")
    if (!mendeleyLiteSubFolder.exists()) return

    val downloadFiles = mendeleyLiteSubFolder.listFiles()

    downloadFiles?.forEach { downloadFile ->
        if (downloadFile.exists()) downloadFile.delete()
        Timber.i("Clearing downloaded file = $downloadFile")
    }
}
```

This clear down worker completes OK, with the logs showing the files have been deleted
however when I use Android Studio Device File Explorer to view my Document sub folder the physical pdf files are still present.

Are my expectations incorrect?

What does this code achieve `context.contentResolver.delete(fileContentUri, null, null)`?

How do I delete physical files from my sub folder?

Comment: `This clear down worker completes OK` Which function? You got two.

Comment: @blackapps The function that employs the content provider e.g. clearDownloadFiles()

Comment: And why do you post two functions if you have only problems with one? Confusing! Post only code that gives you troubles.

Comment: You can call both functions in that case.

Comment: Below Q deleting from the MediaStore is not enough. You should also delete the files yourself in the normal way.

Comment: @blackapps, for now calling both functions will work, however when google stop honouring android:requestLegacyExternalStorage = true, this will again fail. I would like to develop a solution that is future proof and I would also like to understand why delete with content provider doesnt work

Comment: Mostly that works here for Q+. But not when the MediaStore has errors, which sadly often happens. Reboot your device then.

Comment: If you always delete your downloaded files again you could store them in app specific storage. No media store involved then.

Comment: @blackapps i would like to keep the files downloaded by my users, even if they uninstall my app, thats why i choose Documents sub folder